# NHibernate QuerySyntaxException

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Estou tentando retornar a quantidade de objetos que uma query irá retorna.

Se eu executar o seguinte commando:

```
query.ToList().Count
```

O valor é retornado com sucesso, porém se executo o seguinte comando:

```
query.Count()
```

O seguinte erro é retornado:

```
    'query.Count()' threw an exception of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232832
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "A recognition error occurred. [.Count[Admin.CD_MercadoLivre+ProdutosMercadoLivre](.Select[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_Produto,Admin.CD_MercadoLivre+ProdutosMercadoLivre](.Where[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_Produto](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_Produto], Quote((prod, ) => (AndAlso(Equal(prod.IntegraMercadoLivre, p1), Equal(prod.Ativo, p2)))), ), Quote((prod, ) => (new ProdutosMercadoLivre()prod.Idprod.DescricaoString.op_Equality(prod.MercadoLivreIdProduto, NULL) ?  : prod.MercadoLivreIdProdutoprod.TipoIntegracaoMercadoLivreProdutoEnviadoprod.QuantidadeEstoqueDisponivelprod.PrecoEqual(prod.PossuiKit, False) ? prod.PrecoPromocao : 00prod.PossuiKit.ToList[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_ProdutoKit](prod.ProdutoKit, )prod.MercadoLivreTipoAnuncio.Descricaoprod.DataUltimaAlteracaoprod.DataUltimaIntegracaoMercadoLivreprod.Ativoprod.IntegraMercadoLivre)), ), )]"
    QueryString: ".Count[Admin.CD_MercadoLivre+ProdutosMercadoLivre](.Select[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_Produto,Admin.CD_MercadoLivre+ProdutosMercadoLivre](.Where[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_Produto](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_Produto], Quote((prod, ) => (AndAlso(Equal(prod.IntegraMercadoLivre, p1), Equal(prod.Ativo, p2)))), ), Quote((prod, ) => (new ProdutosMercadoLivre()prod.Idprod.DescricaoString.op_Equality(prod.MercadoLivreIdProduto, NULL) ?  : prod.MercadoLivreIdProdutoprod.TipoIntegracaoMercadoLivreProdutoEnviadoprod.QuantidadeEstoqueDisponivelprod.PrecoEqual(prod.PossuiKit, False) ? prod.PrecoPromocao : 00prod.PossuiKit.ToList[DSi.Dominio.Entidades.TAB_ProdutoKit](prod.ProdutoKit, )prod.MercadoLivreTipoAnuncio.Descricaoprod.DataUltimaAlteracaoprod.DataUltimaIntegracaoMercadoLivreprod.Ativoprod.IntegraMercadoLivre)), ), )"
    Source: "NHibernate"
    StackTrace: "   em NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
        em NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
        em NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
        em NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
        em NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
        em NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
        em NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
        em NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
        em NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
        em NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)"
    TargetSite: {Void ThrowQueryException()}
```

A query é construida da seguinte forma:

```
var query = from prod in db.TAB_Produto.Consulta()
    where prod.IntegraMercadoLivre == true
    && prod.Ativo == true
    select new ProdutosMercadoLivre
    {
        Id = prod.Id,
        Descricao = prod.Descricao,
        MercadoLivreID = prod.MercadoLivreIdProduto == null ? string.Empty : prod.MercadoLivreIdProduto,
        Atualizando = prod.TipoIntegracaoMercadoLivreProdutoEnviado,
        Disponivel = prod.QuantidadeEstoqueDisponivel,
        Preco = prod.Preco,
        PrecoPromocao = prod.PossuiKit == false ? prod.PrecoPromocao : 0,
        PrecoMercadoLivre = 0,
        PossuiKit = prod.PossuiKit,
        ProdutoKit = prod.ProdutoKit.ToList(),
        TipoAnuncio = prod.MercadoLivreTipoAnuncio.Descricao,
        DataUltimaAlteracao = prod.DataUltimaAlteracao,
        DataUltimaIntegracaoMercadoLivre = prod.DataUltimaIntegracaoMercadoLivre,

        Ativo = prod.Ativo,
        IntegraMercadoLivre = prod.IntegraMercadoLivre
    };
```

Como poderia arrumar esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ao realizar a chamada com o ToList e depois o Count:**

> query.ToList().Count

O seu software está solicitando para o banco de dados trazer todos os registros, com todas as informações que estão contidas no seu select, para a partir disso, o software realizar a contagem de registros.

**Ao realizar a chamada diretamente com o Count:**

> query.Count()

O seu software está solicitando ao banco a contagem de registros, com a informação direta que você precisa.

**Para resolver o erro, você precisa deixar sua query da seguinte maneira:**

```
var query = from prod in db.TAB_Produto.Consulta()
    where prod.IntegraMercadoLivre == true && prod.Ativo == true
    select prod;
var count = query.Count();
```

O NHibernate não está reconhecendo as funções que existem dentro do select ao utilizar o count, como por exemplo as chamadas com .ToList() e os IFs ternários.

Comment: O problema era justamente o ToList() dentro do select, retornei o objeto "puro" e converti mais tarde, com isso o problema foi resolvido

Comment: Excelente... Uma coisa não relacionada a isso que recomendo fazer é gerar os SQLs das suas consultas, para que a partir disso seja fácil identificar problemas comuns de N+1, funções que não estão sendo chamadas do SGBD, etc...

Comment: O Sql estava retornando certo os dados, só estava dando esse erro na hora de gerar pelo linq, Obrigado pela ajuda